# “Use of ... doesn't match its definition” error when trying to use the hyperref package (with xelatex)

Tags: xetex, hyperref, color

I am getting the following error:

```
! Use of \HyColor@WithModel doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.8 }
```

when trying to run the following file using `latexmk -xelatex`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  citecolor = \color{MidnightBlue}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

---

The culprit here seems to be `\color`. When I give a standard colour such as `red` in `hypersetup`, everything works fine.

Comment: Tried giving `red`, still error.

Comment: Ah, you mean giving `red` without the `\color{...}` part? Why would you add it in anyway?

Comment: `citecolor` accepts a color, which should not include the `\color` command itself.

Comment: To clarify: the correct syntax is `citecolor = MidnightBlue`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: yes, that works thank you. I have no idea why I somehow had the impression that I had to use `\color` when using `dvipsnames`. But the error message was also quite confusing.